# How to change(completely replace) diagram.model in GoJS dynamically?

Tags: angular, rest, gojs

I want to change the GoJS diagram dynamically (with new data JSON acquired using service) with some event on page (say button click) but getting error that the div is already has diagram associated with it
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your stated question, just create the Model somehow (such as by calling the static function **Model.fromJson** if you had written it out using **Model.toJson**) and assign your Diagram's **Diagram.model** property.

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/usingModels.html#SavingAndLoadingModels

But your error message is saying that you are trying to replace an existing Diagram that is associated with an HTML DIV element.  That is different than replacing the **Diagram.model** -- you are replacing the whole **Diagram**.

Each HTML DIV element can have at most one **Diagram** associated with it.  If you want to associate a new Diagram with a DIV, you'll need to set the old Diagram's **Diagram.div** property to null.

More at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/replacingDeleting.html

Comment: the example shared is with JavaScript was somehow didn't work with Angular 7 but I found a way and achieved it